# How to upload image on server by using post API in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have to upload data on the post API in Flutter App but when I hit the API in the app I got 406 Not. Here is the API integration code

```
Future<void> uploadScreenShotAndTitle(
    context, {
    var assignId,
    var userId,
    var unitPrice,
    var title,
    List<File>? image,
    }) async {
        SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        var token = pref.getString('token');
        var headers = {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
        };
        var request = http.MultipartRequest(
           'POST',
            Uri.parse('$baseUrl/api/document/title/upload'),
            );
        request.fields.addAll({
            'assign_id': '$assignId',
            'unit_price': '$unitPrice',
            'user_id': '$userId',
            'title': '$title'
        });
        image?.forEach((element) async {
            request.files.add(
                await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('doc_image', 
                element.path),
            );
        });
request.headers.addAll(headers);
  http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
   print("\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*");
   print(response.statusCode);
     print(response.reasonPhrase);
      print(await response.stream.bytesToString());
 } else {
   print("\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*");
   print(response.statusCode);
   print(response.reasonPhrase);
    print("oooooooooo + ${userId} + oooooooooo ");
   print("oooooooooo + ${assignId} + oooooooooo ");
  }

}

//code for pick image

ElevatedButton(
                         style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(                             backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 178, 67, 72)),
                         child: Text('Upload Photo'),
                         onPressed: () async {
                           // uploadScreenShot();
                           // ImagePicker picker = await
                           final List<XFile> pickImage =
                               await imagePicker.pickMultiImage();
                           if (pickImage != null) {
                             setState(() {
                               images.addAll(images);
                             });
                           } else {
                             print("No image is seleted");
                           }
```